# Invalid hostname for server 1. Please review your configuration

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

II have a problem with phpmyadmin. I have setup apache2 in my local Ubuntu and when I'm trying localhost/phpmyadmin it goes normally to the login page and login properly but I receive a promt " Invalid hostname for server 1. Please review your configuration".

Do anyone knows how to fix this?

in the config.inc.php I have this:

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

instead of `= 'config';`

Comment: Can you share your entire `config.inc.php`, obscuring any sensitive information like hostnames or passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in your config

```
// from
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']='';
// to
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']= 'localhost';
```

check this article for more info: http://www.jkzr.nl/phpmyadmin-invalid-hostname-for-server-1/

Comment: A blank value should activate the default setting (which is 'localhost' anyway).

Comment: For those of using coming past this in 2019, an empty string for host is [supposed to disable the entry](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers).